# pandas: multiple conditions and perform arithmetic operation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with few columns. I am interested to check multiple conditions (>=, <=). Finally, when the conditions are met I am interested to subtract corresponding rows column value from the score.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'diag_name':['diag1','diag2','diag3','diag4','diag5','diag6','diag7'],
'final_score': [100, 90, 89, 100, 100, 99,100], 
'count_corrected': [2,0,2,2,0,1,1]}  
  
# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

To explain my point using an example, if the `final_score` is 100 and `count_corrected` >0 then, corresponding value of `count_corrected` needs to be subtracted from `final_score` value. If not, then `final_score_new` will be same as `final_score`

```
df['final_score_new']=np.where((df.count_corrected>0) & (df.final_score==100),100-df.count_corrected,df['final_score'])

df[['final_score_new','final_score','count_corrected']] ## check
```

I hope I am doing the operation and checks correctly. I thought to confirm so I am not screwing any indices.

Thank you.

Comment: Your solution seems fine, there is some problem?

Comment: I thought to ensure if this is OK and wouldn't make any bug specifically at `100-df.count_corrected` step. Thank you for reviewing.

Comment: Your solution is fine.